# How can I make my program run slower?

Tags: java

This may seem a bit odd, but I need my java program to run slower. I am trying to do lots of math and I am trying to watch it as it does all the math, however, it is computing it to fast and I am getting lost. I want to know if I can slow it down while running or make it compute math slower.

Don't know if this will help but I am using jGrasp and a Windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(***);` after each calculation?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 3):

Just use a debugger. Place a breakpoint on the line your want it to pause on, and you'll be able to see the entire local state when it pauses.

Alternatively, you could just place a sleep statement inside your loop that's running "too fast".

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use Thread.sleep(4000); it pauses your program for 4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to  slow down your program. If you just want to see the computer do the math, write your output to a file instead of to the console. Then you can read it later.

If you really do just want to slow down your program, use `Thread.sleep(msToSleep);`

Answer (score 0):

as others have stated, you can use breakpoints (best solution) but you could also stick a `Scanner#nextLine()` whenever you want to look over your output before proceeding. Thats what I used to do